# Clicking a button fires window.onfocus instead of button.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE:** This only happens when we are debugging

My code looks like this:

```
function onFocus(){
    //do something
}
window.onfocus = onFocus;
//do other things
$('#button1').unbind().bind("click",function(){
    alert('button1 clicked');
});
```

When I click the button, the onFocus code executes, but the button1 click never executes. Why is this happening and is there a workaround ?

Edit:
Full test page:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onFocus(){
    console.log("onfocus triggered");
}
window.onfocus = onFocus;
//do other things
$('#button1').unbind().bind("click",function(){
    console.log("button1 clicked");
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="button1">Test</input>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click on the button, focus event might be firing first on the button.

Comment: @ShaunakD here the window.focus handler is firing, no handler has been defined for button.focus

Comment: Button is part of the window. So on every focus event button,input,anchors this will fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the probable reason is, you might have put an alert inside the `onFocus` function. The focus event will fire first which will show an alert. Then you need to click on the `ok` inorder to close that alert. Then the button click event will not fire.

[**Fiddle with alert**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8hknhwp/6/)

If you put a console.log inside that function, which doesnt need any user input, then the button click event will fire.

[**Fiddle with console.log**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8hknhwp/7/)

In the code which you have pasted in comment will not bind the click event correctly. You need to wrap it in `document.ready`.

```
function onFocus() {
    console.log("onfocus triggered");
}
window.onfocus = onFocus;
//do other things
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        console.log("button1 clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: The Fiddle is working as expected, however the following page generates only "onfocus triggered" log messages:

`<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onFocus(){
    console.log("onfocus triggered");
}
window.onfocus = onFocus;
//do other things
$('#button1').unbind().bind("click",function(){
    console.log("button1 clicked");
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="button1">Test</input>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it like this :

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    alert('button1 clicked');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't like the fact that you have no `<body>` tag?